# Webpack 4 is not bundling just serving from memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm having a trouble with wp4, yesterday i made some builds but now after deleted the dist folder it started giving this problems by using cache or memory serving instead of creating the files

My app structure is :
- root folder
  - public
  - src
  configs here

My webpack config:

```
//const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path')

console.log("Bundling the application..")

module.exports = {

  watch: true,

  target: 'web',

  entry: './src/index.js',


  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'env'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            minimize: true
          }
        })
      },
      /*{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: '',
              modules: true
            }
          },
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },*/
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        /*loader: "file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]", */
        query: {
            name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'web.css',
        disable: false,
        allChunks: true
    }),
    /*new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),*/
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Track on Performance",
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html"
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx']
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    compress: true
  }
};
```

I have no errors on the console, as you can also i've tried mini css extract but the problem is still here

Comment: how are you running your command? There are few differences depending on how you are starting it.

Comment: Yes i found, i was running webpack-server but now i figured out after a year that i need to do webpack -w